# How to show that a projection matrix is invariant w.r.t the choice of a g-inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse, projection-matrices, invariance

Let X be an $(nxk)$-matrix (not necessarily of full rank) and $P = X(X'X)^-X'$, i should show that P is invariant with respect to the choice of the g-inverse of $X'X$.
As a hint I should first verify that $PX=X$. That wasn't a problem since $(X'X)^-(X'X)$ cancels out.
I thought about showing the invariance the same way, so that $(X'X)^-(X'X)$ cancels out again, but honestly i got no idea how to do it or even start.

Comment: How does that cancel out? Also, what is the definition you use for generalized inverse?

Comment: As $PX=X(X'X)^-X'X$ the last two terms give the Identitymatrix and thus only X left. We use the definition that $X^-$ is a generalized inverse of X if $XX^-X=X$

Comment: It doesn't give the identity matrix (unless $X'X$ is invertible, which is *not assumed*).

Comment: ...that is a problem. :(